# Making a position:static (or :relative) element span the width of the page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to have a top "tray" for an advertisement. It can slide away beyond the border of the page, with a javascript script. A "divider" below it holds the close icon, and is mostly cosmetic, as it gets fixed when the page is scrolled past a point. (This is to prevent the browser's theme from screwing up the page design).

My problem is before the divider gets `position:fixed` by javascript, it needs to be either `position:relative` or `position:static`, as absolute positioning will take it out of the flow of the page. When I set it to `position:static` and `width:100%` there is a margin that shows the background image through it. I want it to cover the entire top of the page. I've searched for a solution, but I can't find anything on how to remove this border. It is easier to explain using the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NN4Xt/1/): At the top there is the part with the red border, and directly below it a divider fixes to the page when you scroll down. I cannot figure out how to get the red border and the divider (before it becomes fixed) to span the width of the page.

Here's the offending piece of the HTML:

```
    <div class = "adTray">

    <div class = "ad"></div>
    <div class = "ad"></div>
</div>

<div  class="topBorder"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.adTray{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

#topBorderScrolled{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
}
.topBorder{
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background: rgb(68,68,68); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%, rgba(38,38,38,1) 50%, rgba(20,20,20,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(68,68,68,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(51,51,51,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(38,38,38,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(20,20,20,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 50%,rgba(20,20,20,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 50%,rgba(20,20,20,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 50%,rgba(20,20,20,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 50%,rgba(20,20,20,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#141414',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width:100%;
    height:15px;

    border:1px solid #111111;
}
```

I hope all that made sense.

Comment: **normalize** your css! that is the browsers default margin/padding showing up. http://jsfiddle.net/NN4Xt/2/

Comment: @PeterVR I see. I already tried to add all of the `padding:0`s and `margin:0`s, but it seems I had missed one. Thanks! I now have a different problem... `width:100%` makes it just slightly larger than the window, making a permanent horizontal scroll.  Is there an alternative to 100% width?

Comment: Just don't add any width. The defaults will make a block level element take up the full width of it's parent. Or you could work with `box-sizing: border-box` if you insist on defining the width.

Comment: Alright! That worked. Boy do I feel silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reset.css to normalise all styles, read about one of the reset CSSs available here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

Another quick way to do it would be to set margin on your body to zero, eg. `body {margin: 0}` but the recommended way to do it is to use a reset.css.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into the CSS reset thing. Oddly, it's the first time I've heard about one! I'm also having the issue with the width, see my comment in response to PeterVR

Comment: Apologies about the late response but looks like @PeterVR beat me to it! :)

All block elements have a default width of 100% of their parent, the reason an element with 100% goes outside the parent bounds is mostly because it has a border or padding applied to it (which extends it by the width of the border/padding past the width of the parent).